# format indentation in XPages JS Editor

Tags: javascript, editor, xpages

The XML editor has the function  to properly format the source XML by indention. Very useful in finding unmatched  etc. I have search but can not find a similar function in the JavaScript editor to indent using the { } which would be really handy and make the code much easier to follow and catch improper placement of the { }'s. 
Is there a built in function to do this, or is there an add on of some sort that can be installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSJS** code can be formatted automatically with

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>  or
- mouse click right + menu Source/Format

[image]

Unfortunately, this is not available for **SSJS** code.
Workaround: copy SSJS code into CSJS code window, format it and copy it back to SSJS code window.

Comment: Thanks, Does not make any sense that it can be done in CSJS but not SSJS editor, but then.... This should be a feature request, but I have no way of making that.

Comment: It is probably not available for SSJS because of the additional @-functions with their own syntax. The CSJS code formatter is part of normal Eclipse IDE. IBM didn't expand it for SSJS code, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In preferences there is JjavaScript > Code Style > Formatter, which can be applied via JavaScript > Editor > Save Actions. Does that work? If the editor doesn't allow that hook, I suspect it's unlikely to take account of any add on.

Comment: The code formats OK on entry but does not seem to re-indent if it gets out of sequence. ie does not indent everything between } and { if they get out of sync.